# Photo Diode Receiver

Tags: infrared, photodiode, light, receiver

I have designed a 5KHz Photo Diode Receiver circuit that Consists of a number of blocks. first stage of this circuit is a TIA.
I have problem with DC IR Light (Like **SUN Light**), when sun light shine on photo diode, i can't detect 5KHz signal.[image] for solving this problem i decrease feedback resistor's value in TIA block, And because of this i can't detect signal over long distances.
now my question directly is **How can I To be ineffective SUN light**.
Can anyone help me correct this block?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How can I be ineffective SUN light*

Add an op-amp stage that amplifies (to restore gain) but uses capacitive coupling to block DC light changes or slow changing AC signals thus preventing variable sun-light levels from being a problem. There are probably some materials available that block a lot of sunlight out too.